# How to check Android target platform of devices on AVD Manager before installation?

Tags: android, android-studio, avd-manager

Working on Android Studio emulators, the device definitions on the AVD Manager speak about the resolution of the device and not the target of the Android. I want to set emulators for Android versions from 6 to 10. How to proceed?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Once you select the device you can select the system image

[image: avd system image]

Comment: Not sure how to enter to this Virtual Device Configuration from AVD Manager Windows. There is a Create New Virtual Device button, but I can't any dropdown or popup window for selecting a System Image.

Comment: Once you select a device (i.e. Nexus 5X), press the "Next" button at the bottom (missing from your screenshot)